# Can't link Multiple fields in Data Extension in Contact Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

Hello I have a DE containing the following fields that I would like to link to Contact Builder:
Contacts_ID --> Contact Key
Email Address --> Email Address

However, they won't let me link both. They only allow me to link the Contact_ID and the Contact Key. The email address should be related to the Email Address field in the Email object though

Comment: what is the use case you are trying to achieve? The contact model is referenced only in entry filters and decision split within JB (also mobile lists)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to link one Data Extension to the Contact Record. In Data Designer, create a new attribute group and link your first DE to the Contact record, you will be only able to set one relationship there (for example, Contacts_ID --> Contact Key). The system will know how to link email in your DE to the Contact Record, as long as the email field is set to email type in your DE. 
Then, you can link additional data extensions and you can links as many fields together as you wish, as long as they are the same data type.

[image]